# Magento 1.9.3 SSL added just work with /index.php pages in frontend

Tags: magento-1.9, frontend, ssl, 404-page

I recently installed an SSL certificate on my test server and I got a problem with my front end. All the web pages return 404 if I don't put **/index.php/**.

I put **`Use Web Server Rewrites`** as **`No`** and **`Use Secure URLs in Frontend`** as **`Yes`** but nothing works.

Please help..

Comment: Hi, make sure you have url_rewrite extension enabled in your server.

Comment: Use Web Server Rewrites - YES, check you have .htaccess

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Meetanshi said, make sure you have **`mod_rewrite`** enabled on the server or not. **`mod_rewrite`** should be enabled to allow URLs without index.php.

To check whether it is enabled or not, do one of the following:

> **Method 1:** Create a file (say: info.php) in the document root and paste below code:

```
<?php
phpinfo();
?>
```

Now hit the URL **yourwebsiteurl/info.php** and check for **`mod_rewrite`** under **Loaded Modules** section. If it does not exist, it means that server does not have mod_rewrite (URL rewrites) enabled.

> **Method 2:** Write anything wrong in the **.htaccess** file under document root and reload the website.

If mod_rewrite is enabled, then you should get Internal Server Error. If it does not happen, you must enable mod_rewrite on the server.

To know how to enable mod_rewrite, you can check instructions [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/48362/how-to-enable-mod-rewrite-in-apache).

Please let me know if it helped.

Comment: Thanks all, you are right mod_rewrite was disable on my server, I activated it on my Apache, restarted it and work well now.